# Terminology; Basis for a Topology

Tags: general-topology, terminology

In section 13 of Munkres's topology, he defines a basis $\mathcal{B}$ containing subsets $B$ of a set $X$. One of the first things he proves is that the resulting collection, $\mathcal{T}$, is in fact a topology.

Here is my confusion. He uses "is an element of $\tau$" and "is open" interchangeably. But after we have a topology, we can call its elements open sets, so this seems circular to me. Is the idea that elements generated by a basis are open, and then we check this is actually a topology? Otherwise,  it seems to me that we should be talking about membership in $\mathcal{T}$ and only use the notion of openness after checking that it satisfies the axioms for a topology.

Comment: Membership in $\mathcal{T}$ and "being open" are equivalent facts.

Comment: So we can say "open" even without knowing we have a topology yet?

Comment: Might be more accurate to say "provisionally-open", but no one wants to do that, I guess.

Comment: @Brad G. When you "open set", you must be referring to some element of a topology. Conversely, when you refer to an element of a topology, you are referring to an "open set". But be careful: when two people say "open set" , they may not be referring to the same thing, because there are lots of different topologies.

Comment: To be strict, we should say $\mathcal{T}$-open to make the dependency on the family of sets $\mathcal{T}$ explicit. A set is $X$ is $\mathcal{T}$-open iff $X \in \mathcal{T}$. This definition works whether or not $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology, so there is no real circularity.

Comment: After my earlier comment, I checked the text (see my comment on the accepted answer). Munkres was writing very carefully and seems to me to have completely covered the OP's point of concern. Moral: consult the original source if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are entirely right. Munkres is abusing terminology a little bit by calling the sets in $\mathcal{T}$ "open" before we actually know that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology.

That said, you don't need to fear any kind of circular reasoning. Munkres never uses any facts about open sets in his proof, he only uses the name as an abbreviation for $U \in \mathcal{T}$. For instance, here:

> Now let us take an indexed familiy $\{ U_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in J}$, of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ and show that
>
> $$U = \bigcup_{\alpha \in J} U_\alpha$$
> belongs to $\mathcal{T}$. Given $x \in U$, there is an index $\alpha$ such that $x \in U_\alpha$. Since $U_\alpha$ is open, there is a basis element $x \in B \subset U_\alpha$. Then $x \in B$ and $B \subset U$, so that $U$ is open, by definition.

Munkres is showing that axiom $(2)$ for a topology holds, by checking that the union of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ is again an element of $\mathcal{T}$. Recall $V \in \mathcal{T}$ if and only if for each $x \in V$, there is a $B$ in the basis with $x \in B \subset V$. He uses the word "open", but you can see that making the replacements

- "Since $U_\alpha$ is open" $\rightsquigarrow$ "Since each $U_\alpha \in \mathcal{T}$"
- "so that $U$ is open" $\rightsquigarrow$ "so that $U \in \mathcal{T}$

doesn't change the proof at all.

In fact, in the next paragraph (where he proves axiom $(3)$ holds), he uses this (slightly clearer) terminology instead.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I am glad the OP is happy with your answer, but there is no abuse of terminology here.  If you check the text, Munkres actually explicitly defines towards the top of the cited section of the book what it means for a set $U$ to be open in the context of a proposed basis for a topology. This maybe "overloads" the definition given earlier of an open set with respect to a topology, but overloading (or in this case, giving a provisional alternative definition) is not abuse of terminology.

Comment: @RobArthan -- While I do agree with you regarding the "overloading" (you'll have to take my word that I noticed the definition you're referring to and considered mentioning it in my answer), I still think it's abusive, even if it's not _very_ abusive. What seems harmless to us can be confusing to a newcomer (as indeed it was to OP), and I think that the quibble of "overloading notation" vs "absuse of notation" is comparatively minor compared to the pedagogical benefits of agreeing with OP that the terminology was potentially confusing.

Comment: OK.  I am happy to agree to differ, but I will note that no-one calls it abuse of notation when we overload the symbol "+" by using it for scalar addition and vector addition when talking about vector spaces. However, perhaps Munkres could have presented his ideas in a better order.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of "being open" is "being in $\mathcal{T}$". A *topology* is nothing more than the collection of the open subsets that are defined on a set. In this case, even though it is not proven (yet) that $\mathcal{T}$ is indeed a topology, as some have already pointed out in the comments, membership in $\mathcal{T}$ and *openness* are really the same thing, since *openness* is not an absolute property of a set (something that is or is not true regardless of the context), but rather a relative property. Hence, it doesn't make sense to say that it is *false* to say that a set is open, even if $\mathcal{T}$ hasn't been proven to be a topology yet. So for me there is no problem whatsoever.